# LXDE: PCManFM Thumbnails of images > 2MB are not shown

Tags: lxde, thumbnails, pcmanfm

Im using LXDE, with PCManFM but images bigger than 2MB are just shown with image-symbol and not with the thumbnail. How Can I change that behavior?

Comment: What File manager are you using ? pcmanfm ?

Comment: Yes. 15-spaces.

Comment: This solution works up to a max of 32768 kb. I'm not sure what to do since I need more for a full frame camera's images.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default pcmanfm limits the size of files to show thumnails to 2 Mb.

Go in the menu Edit > Preferences > Display

At the bottom, change the value of  "Do not generate thumbnails for file exceeding this size" from 2000 KB to a larger size.

10000 KB (10MB) perhaps. Depends on the size of your pictures.

Comment: Sometimes you are just blind. I was even on that page but didnt get the information. Thanks, worked!

Comment: It works, but it's strange that I'm viewing PNGs of very small size (eg 100Kb) but I have to set that limit to 65536Kb in order for the thumbnail to be shown...

Answer (score 2):

> It works, but it's strange that I'm viewing PNGs of very small size
>   (eg 100Kb) but I have to set that limit to 65536Kb in order for the
>   thumbnail to be shown... – Yan King Yin Jun 13 '17 at 10:07

I have just noticed this issue with JPG files (85 in a folder) of maybe 500 KiB - and they would generate a thumbnail. Other images (maybe larger ones of 1.1 MiB, maybe random size, I forget) would NOT show a thumbnail. This is despite adjusting the above setting to 3500 KiB for the thumbnail generation threshold. The largest image is 1.2 MiB approx.

I just experimented and adjusted it UPWARDS to 10 MiB, and suddenly it works! Bug-gery! I couldn't establish a logical pattern to it apart from this.
Same principle as you, it seems, different threshold. I suggest a RAM allocation issue subjective to installation, but am not skilled enough to debug this (yet!)

PCManFM 1.2.4 on LXLE 14.04 (yes I know it's obsolete but is the bug gone?).

Comment: still a bug, anything larger than 150kb wont generate with the default threshold

Comment: Thank you so much, that had been bugging me for years. I had exactly the problem you describe with the defaults. I set the limit to 12048kb and it didn't help. I then set it to 32MB (the max - I actually entered 64000kb and it decided on 32768kb itself) and now all my images have thumbnails. Yeeeeehaa! Happy Geek!