# How to see photo icons in Lubuntu file manager

Tags: icons, filemanager

In File Manager PCManFM, when I open a folder with pictures, I can only see the icon that represents a picture file.

I would like to be able to see the icons of the pictures as those pictures themselves. Otherwise, I have to open the pictures in image viewer and flip through all photos in order to find the one I'm looking for, or to know which photo is which.

I have tried and tried, and searched for the answer here before asking this.

How would I do this?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/301503/lxde-pcmanfm-thumbnails-of-images-2mb-are-not-shown

Answer (score 2):

Go under Edit --> Preferences --> Display, and make sure that you have a check mark on Show thumbnails of file.  See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I changed the value for

**"Do not generate thumbnails for files exceeding this size:"** to `10000` instead of `2048`.